# Заменить символ в строках таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle

Какой командой можно заменить первый символ во всех строках где он равняется конкретному числу. К примеру такая таблица:

```
ID   CODE
1    120012
2    120001
3    000000
```

нужно заменить 12 на 88, причем только если это первые два символа, и если они вообще есть. Т.е.:

```
ID   CODE
1    880012
2    880001
3    000000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE table
SET code = '88' || SUBSTR(code,3)
WHERE SUBSTR(code,1,2) = '12'
```